# Jade in ExecJS context

Tags: ruby, pug, execjs

Very simply, I am having trouble running the compiled jade.js from [jade-lang](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) file in execjs.

If I include jade.js in an html file

```
jade.compile
```

returns a function.

When I do the following:

```
require 'execjs'

source  = <<-src
  var window = {};
  #{open('jade.js').read}
  var jade = window.jade;
src
context = ExecJS.compile source
context.eval "jade.compile"
 => nil
```

nil gets returned by eval.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I've searched stack overflow, and even found a few gems that do this the same way as I am doing it, but when I execute on my system, it doesn't work. I've tried with therubyracer and node as my execjs runtimes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when the return from execjs is a function, it returns nil. So:

```
context.eval "jade.compile.toString()"
=> "function....."
```

Likewile

```
context.eval "jade.compile(#{template.to_json}).toString()"
=> "function...."
```

and

```
context.eval "jade.compile(#{template.to_json})()"
=> "some html"
```

This makes sense since the extract_result method of [execjs/external_runtime.rb](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb) (line 62 as of this writing) uses JSON.decode, which will not decode a function. Only a derivative of object.